# References for resources used in test

Tags: metrics

I am looking for some references for the following statements:

1. "The size of the test code code is/can be greater that the size of the product code"
2. "The amount of resources spent on developing and maintaining test code can be greater than those spent for the tested code"

Basically I am looking for some clear examples or some some academic resources. Can anyone help with any of these?

Answer (score 1):

[As Chris answered over on the closed SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317355/references-for-resources-used-in-test/6317466#6317466): there are articles [like this one (PDF)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.108.147&rep=rep1&type=pdf) or [this from its reference list (PDF).](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.7992&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: the "like this one" link is broken.

Comment: @user246: Thanks!  I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html) link from xUnit Patterns